# Example of a Borel measure which is not a Radon measure

Tags: measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $(X,\mathcal{U})$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and $\mathcal B$ the Borel $\sigma$-Algebra respectively. We call a measure $\mu : \mathcal B \to [0, \infty]$ a Borel measure, if for every compact set $K\in \mathcal B$ it follows $\mu(B) < \infty$. Further $\mu$ is called inner regular if $\forall A \in \mathcal B\quad \mu(A) = \sup\{\mu(K)| K \text{ is compact & } K \subset A\}$. Now we defined a Radon measure as an inner regular Borel measure.
Is there an example of a Borel measure which is not inner regular and hence not Radon?

Hopefully I am not creating duplicates here. Due to the fact that there are some different definitions I haven't found a proper answer.

Edit: I've read something about Dieudonné's Measure which is highly not trivial, so is there a simpler example?

Comment: Have you read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4330877/693577)?

Comment: You cannot do this in a separable metric space, so you will have to do something at least a little nontrivial.  Those who do not know the term "Dieudonné's Measure" ... the $\{0,1\}$-valued measure on the ordinal space $[0,\omega_1)$ that vanishes on all sets $[0,\alpha], \alpha < \omega_1$.

Comment: @joe: Yes I have seen this but I actually do not see how this is Borel, I think in $\mathbb R$ is every set a compact set regarding the cofinite topology ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657684/compactness-in-finite-complement-topology
hence $\mu(B)<\infty $ can not hold for every $B \subset \mathbb R$?

Comment: oh, yes, you are correct. I guess that answer didn't require "locally finite" in the definition of a Borel measure.